# Hide part of an axis in a matplolib figure

Tags: matplotlib, axes

How can I modulate the length of the yaxis of a matplotlib plot, as in the following figure: [image]

In addition, how can I modulate the thickness of the yaxis?

Comment: what do you mean by modulate? do you just want to change the y axis limits?

Comment: No, it's not a ylim() problem.  The yaxis of this plot represents voltages from -6 to 6 uV. However, I want to draw the axis from -4 to 4uV only, as in the figure. In other words, I want to remove the yaxis line from -6 to -4 and from 4 to 6uV.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer. One need to use ax.spines['left'].set_bounds(4, -4).